# How to filter TableQuery with the list of IDs?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm really new to Slick and Scala and I'm strugling with filtering the query with the list of ids.

```
productsNeededIds // = "1,2,3,4,5" - list of Ids of products
```

Question: How can I use .filter to get a query with all the ids from the splitted list?

```
   def productsWithIds(productsNeededIds: String)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[List[ProductsREST]] = {

    var splitedArray :Array[String] = productsNeededIds.split(",")
    val query = Products.filter(_.prodId === splitedArray)// what should be here instead of ===splitedArray?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `inSet` method:

```
def productsWithIds(productsNeededIds: String)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[List[ProductsREST]] = {

  val splitedSet: Set[String] = productsNeededIds.split(",").toSet
  val query = Products.filter(_.prodId.inSet(splitedSet))
}
```

That's assuming your product IDs are strings. If they're `Int`s instead, you should map your `splittedSet` to `Int`s first, of course.